# How to use Gtk.Popover() in Vala?

Tags: programming, gtk, vala

I can't bind Gtk.Popover() to button.

Answer (score 3):

You can associate the popover creation with a button event, like in the following example:

```
var button = new Gtk.Button (); 
var imag = new Gtk.Image.from_icon_name ("help-info", Gtk.IconSize.MENU);
button.add (imag);
button.clicked.connect (() => {
    var pop = new Gtk.Popover ();
    //set popover content
    pop.set_parent_pop (window);
    pop.move_to_widget (button);
    pop.show_all ();
    pop.present ();
    pop.run ();
    pop.destroy ();
});
```

More info about *Gtk.Popover* :

[Valadoc.org](http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Popover)